Problem with Leap Frog Integration simulating the Earth around the Sun
I have been trying to implement Leap Frog integration for the system of the Earth orbiting the Sun:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


#define Grav    6.6726e-11             // m^3/kg/s^2
#define Msun    1.989e30               // kg
#define Mearth  5.973e24               // kg
#define Dse     1.496e11               // distance Sun-Earth in meters



void LeapFrog(int n) {

    // Initial Conditions
    double x0 = Dse;
    double y0 = 0;

    double vx0 = 0;
    double vy0 = sqrt(Grav*Msun/Dse);

    double px0 = Mearth*vx0;
    double py0 = Mearth*vy0;

    // Delta time
    double dt = 0.01;

    //we create a file for saving the coordinates
    std::ofstream outputFile("LF.dat");
    outputFile << x0 << " " << y0 << std::endl;


    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {

        double x = x0 + dt*px0/(2*Mearth);
        double y = y0 + dt*py0/(2*Mearth);

        outputFile << x << " " << y << std::endl;

        double px = px0 - dt* Grav* Msun * x/pow(sqrt(x*x + y*y), 3);
        double py = py0 - dt* Grav* Msun* y/pow(sqrt(x*x + y*y), 3);

        double x2 = x + dt*px/(2*Mearth);
        double y2 = y + dt*py/(2*Mearth);

        
        outputFile << x2 << " " << y2 << std::endl;

        //initialize the values for the following step
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;

        px0 = px;
        py0 = py;

    }

    outputFile.close();
}



int main() {

    LeapFrog(48);

    return 0;

}

...and I keep getting the same error where I only get a straight vertical line instead of an orbit.
I have tried almost everything and different implementations of the algorithm, the problem is also that I need to do a kick-drift-kick integration. I was expecting getting a correct orbit of the Earth around the Sun.

I would avoid using macros to define constants in C++. inline constexpr double [BLAH] = x; works just as well, and doesn't haul macro baggage along with it.

not sure if tahts the issue, but would definitely choose more "natural" units where you do not have huge exponents on every quantity.

How far were you expecting the earth to travel in 0.48 s?

OK, you have a few problems - mostly physical.
Your code is going to simulate 48 * 0.01 = 0.48s, but there are 3.16e7 s in a year, so it won't be much of an orbit. Increase the number of steps and make the timestep a realistic fraction of the orbital time (circumference/velocity).
px and py refer to momentum, so you need total force, not total acceleration in their change: you forgot Mearth! Change to
double px = px0 - dt* Grav* Msun * Mearth * x/pow(sqrt(x*x + y*y), 3);

and similarly for py.
You should update x0 and y0 to x2 and y2 at the end of the step, not x and y. Also, you only need to output once a timestep.
The following plots a circular orbit. Change the initial velocity a bit if you want an ellipse.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double Grav = 6.6726e-11;        // m^3/kg/s^2 (Universal gravitational constant)
double Msun = 1.989e30;          // kg
double Mearth = 5.973e24;        // kg
double Dse = 1.496e11;           // distance Sun-Earth in meters
int nsteps = 1000;               // Timesteps per orbit


void LeapFrog(int n)
{
    // Initial Conditions
    double x0 = Dse;
    double y0 = 0;

    double vx0 = 0;
    double vy0 = sqrt(Grav*Msun/Dse);

    double px0 = Mearth*vx0;
    double py0 = Mearth*vy0;

    // Timestep
    double dt = ( 2 * 3.141592654 * Dse / vy0 ) / nsteps;      // fraction of a year

    // Create a file for saving the coordinates
    ofstream outputFile("LF.dat");
    outputFile << x0 << " " << y0 << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        double x = x0 + dt*px0/(2*Mearth);
        double y = y0 + dt*py0/(2*Mearth);

        double px = px0 - dt * Grav* Msun * Mearth * x / pow(sqrt(x*x + y*y), 3);        // Don't forget the earth!
        double py = py0 - dt * Grav* Msun * Mearth * y / pow(sqrt(x*x + y*y), 3);

        double x2 = x + dt*px/(2*Mearth);
        double y2 = y + dt*py/(2*Mearth);

        outputFile << x2 << " " << y2 << std::endl;

        // Initialise the values for the following step
        x0 = x2;
        y0 = y2;

        px0 = px;
        py0 = py;
    }
}


int main()
{
    LeapFrog( nsteps * 1 );                   // One orbit
}


Wow! This really solved all my problems, they were such stupid mistakes, I feel a little embarrased Thank you very much sir, this is just what I needed :)
